# Загрузка и обновление приложения с сервера

Tags: java, android, update

Пытаюсь реализовать обновление приложения с сервера.
Для android 8 работает, т.е. апк загружается и далее пользователь подтверждает установку и приложение ставится.
Но на android 10 не работает.
Ниже приведу код уже для установки скачанной апк:

```
 private void installApk() {
            try {
                String PATH = Objects.requireNonNull(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)).getAbsolutePath();
                File file = new File(PATH + "/app.apk");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                    Uri downloaded_apk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                    intent.setDataAndType(downloaded_apk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                        mContext.grantUriPermission(mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", downloaded_apk, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    }
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: А что пишет в логах?

Comment: В системе есть такая настройка, как разрешение на установка приложений. Нужно дать разрешение

Comment: @Barmaley ошибок нет. Переделал getExternalFilesDir на getExternalStorage (в примере видел), тоже не работает.

Comment: @ArtyMorris разрешения конечно есть

Comment: Эммм... а почему 2 раза `startActivity()`?

Answer (score 3):

Пишут, что

> On Android 10+, ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE was deprecated as an action, with Google steering developers to use PackageInstaller instead.

Все логично, работать не должно. Так что надо идти за [PackageInstaller](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller)